# How to add one button to all of my forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

C#:

I have many forms, I want to add one button with the same function.
(an exit button) to all of them.

I don't want to duplicate the button.
is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can use `User Control`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx

Comment: You can use inheritance to create a FormWithExitButton class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will add exit buttons to all the forms including the form where you invoke this method. Add this method in the form where you want it to invoke.

```
public void AddExitButtons() {
    foreach(Form frm in Application.OpenForms) {    
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "exitBtn";
        btn.Text = "Exit";
        btn.Location = new Point(100, 100); // Add x and y position to where you need it.
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.exitBtn_Click);
        frm.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

public void exitBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
}
```

or if you don't want to add the exit button in the form where you use this method, refer to this code:

```
public void AddExitButtons() {
    foreach(Form frm in Application.OpenForms) {    
        if(frm.Name != this.Name) {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Name = "exitBtn";
            btn.Text = "Exit";
            btn.Location = new Point(100, 100); // Add x and y position to where you need it.
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.exitBtn_Click);
            frm.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }
}

public void exitBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comment, I assume you would like to add those buttons on all tab pages of a tab control. Here the code goes like:

```
public void AddExitButtons() {
    foreach(TagPage tabPge in tabControl1.TabPages) {   
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = "exitBtn";
        btn.Text = "Exit";
        btn.Location = new Point(100, 100); // Add x and y position to where you need it.
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.exitBtn_Click);
        tabPge.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

public void exitBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: Thank You .

I'm sorry for the mistake , 

I meant that i need to add one button  with the same function to all of my **tab control** (I only have one Form).

Comment: I've added the code that works for tab control.

Comment: Thank You man , It Works like magic :)